# get values from SQL DB with php and use it in HTML5

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

I have a HTML5 file respectively a simple webpage.

and I have a php file.
this file includes a function getKursname(string)
The function is working properly when called in the php file.
This all happens on XAMPP.

I now want to update some values and strings in my html page.
this should happen only on load.

this ist a code the code in the html:

```
<div class="w3-bar" id="myNavbar">
    <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-black w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large w3-right" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggleFunction()" title="Toggle Navigation Menu">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#home" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"><i class="myfont icon-heart"></i> HOME</a>
    <a href="#about" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small"><i class="myfont icon-users"></i> &UumlBER UNS</a>
    <a href="#portfolio" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small"><i class="myfont icon-th"></i> KURSE</a>
    <a href="#contact" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small"><i class="myfont icon-mail-alt"></i> KONTAKT</a>

    </a>
  </div>
```

I want to have the innerhtml (e.g. KONTAKT) 
to be read from the database.

the php function returns a string.

I can call the funcion with getKursname(string) within php.

my idea was:

```
<a href="#contact" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small"><i class="myfont icon-mail-alt"></i>getKursname("kurs1")</a>
```

but this is not working... :-(

thanks in advance
Dirk

Comment: your question is extremely unspecific. the sql tag seems unrelated, the function name is unrelated, it being html5 seems unrelated. you provide no code at all, and your problem description is essentially: "I now want to update some values and strings in my html page. this should happen only on load.", which is not at all precise. on load of what? and what should inject the "values" and "strings"? default would be, that the page is already generated with those values and strings. but since you provide no code at all ... please be more specific, and bring code.

Comment: I edited... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a directory structure similar to this:

```
www/
  index.html
  functions.php
```

and you want to inject the content before the index.html is sent to the browser.

In which case, the solution would be, to rename index.html to index.php and at the point where you want the output of the function, you write

```
<?php include_once 'functions.php'; echo getKursname("kurs1"); ?>
```

(or require_once instead of include_once, and you have to include it only once *before* it is used, to load the function definition)

however, standard is to put includes in the header:

#### index.php

```
<?php 
     require_once 'functions.php';
?><html>
  <head><!-- ... --></head>
  <body><!-- ... other stuff -->
     <?=getKursname("kurs1");?>
     <!-- rest of page -->
  </body></html>
```

to clarify: `<?=[something] ?>` is short for `<?php echo [something] ?>` and everything between `<?php` and the next `?>` is evaluated by php, everything else (like the html code) is just printed as is.

Comment: oh man, that works... thanks a lot! I hope this will do it for all my stuff... :-)

Comment: @Dirk would you mind marking it as an answer, please ;o)